# java based configuration for Spring data solr 3.0.6 release

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, solr, spring-data-solr

I am trying to use Spring solr starter in spring boot using java based configuration.
I have read official doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/reference/html/#solr.annotation, there is only a sample to connect EmbeddedSolrServerFactory using the below code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(
    basePackages = "com.tutorial.demo.repositories"
)
@ComponentScan
public class ApplicationConfig {
    @Bean
    public SolrClient solrClient() throws Exception {
         EmbeddedSolrServerFactory factory = new 
         EmbeddedSolrServerFactory("classpath:com/acme/solr");
         return factory.getSolrServer();
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrOperations solrTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new SolrTemplate(solrClient());
   }}
```

would anyone help me how to connect to my solr server (not embedded one) by using java based configuration in spring data solr. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried ? what doesn't work ? your question is too broad. you need to narrow it down to where are you facing problem and show some code which you are using now?

Comment: @root545 Thanks for your comment. I updated my question.

Comment: @josh Did you get your answer? I am having the same problem. Please let me know the solution if you got it

Comment: @user3029929 yes, I did. Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(
    basePackages = "path for your solr repository package"
)
@ComponentScan
public class ApplicationConfig {
private final SolrPropertyConfig solrPropertyConfig;

public ApplicationConfig(SolrPropertyConfig solrPropertyConfig) {
    this.solrPropertyConfig = solrPropertyConfig;
}

@Bean
public SolrClient solrClient() throws Exception {
    return new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrPropertyConfig.getSolrHost()).build();
}

@Bean
public SolrOperations solrTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new SolrTemplate(solrClient());
}
}
```

Comment: thanks, I am also having problem of choosing solr core dynamically. Can you please let me know how we can choose solr core dynamically with spring-data-solr 3.0.6 version

Comment: @user3029929 When you create an entity and annotate it with @SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "yourCorename"), the document with be persist or retrieved from the the core name you provided above. Then you only need to add the solr host in your configuration.

Comment: I cannot annonate @SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "yourCorename") core name , because i need to add core name dynamically